# How to make gridview text align to middle and more fluid?

Tags: html, css, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, gridview

Sorry, i am noob here. I tried to make my text to align to middle and not sticking to the border of the table. However, i tried numerous code horizontal align, cssclass in the properties and content keep not align in the middle.
So, how i fluid my gridview or make gridview the text align and not make it so cramp?
[image: Image not align]

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvViewFeed" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" AutoGenerateSelectButton="True" CellPadding="4" style="align-items:center;" CssClass="table-bordered" DataKeyNames="FeedbackID" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" Width="100%" OnSelectedIndexChanged="gvViewFeed_SelectedIndexChanged" HeaderStyle-CssClass="centerHeaderText" BorderStyle="Solid" CellSpacing="2" HorizontalAlign="Justify">
            <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="FeedbackID" HeaderText="FeedbackID" >
                <ItemStyle Wrap="True" HorizontalAlign="Right" />
                </asp:BoundField>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="MemberID" HeaderText="MemberID" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="DateTimePosted" HeaderText="DateTimePosted" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Title" HeaderText="Title" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Text" HeaderText="Text" />
            </Columns>
            <EditRowStyle BackColor="#999999" />
            <FooterStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <HeaderStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <PagerStyle BackColor="#284775" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
            <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F6F3" ForeColor="#333333" />
            <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#E2DED6" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
            <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9E7E2" />
            <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#506C8C" />
            <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#FFFDF8" />
            <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6F8DAE" />
        </asp:GridView>
    </p>
    <asp:GridView ID="gvResponse" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="4" CssClass="Table" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" Width="80%" style="align-items:center;">
        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="ResponseID" HeaderText="ResponseID" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="DateTimePosted" HeaderText="DateTimePosted" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Text" HeaderText="Text" />
        </Columns>
        <EditRowStyle BackColor="#999999" />
        <EmptyDataTemplate>
            No Record Found!
        </EmptyDataTemplate>
        <FooterStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <PagerStyle BackColor="#284775" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
        <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F6F3" ForeColor="#333333" />
        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#E2DED6" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
        <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9E7E2" />
        <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#506C8C" />
        <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#FFFDF8" />
        <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6F8DAE" />
    </asp:GridView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
<RowStyle HorizontalAlign="Center"></RowStyle>

<ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center"></ItemStyle>
```

For more information check [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479342.aspx) GridView examples.

Comment: it only align the text column only

Comment: @azaz Please check MSDN link at bottom of my post.

Answer (score 0):

Add your controls in `center` rag in `templatefield`:

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <center>
        <asp:Button ID="btnEdit" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-primary btn-sm" Text="EDIT" />
        <asp:Button ID="btnDelete" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-danger btn-sm" Text="DELETE" />
    </center>
</ItemTemplate>
```